# Link doesn't hide after some time capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I use capybara to test this code which located in my Comment model (5 minutes are conventional):

```
 def editable?
    self.created_at < (Time.now - 5.minute)
 end
```

The view of link:

```
- unless comment.editable?
  = link_to 'Edit', edit_category_theme_comment_path(@category, @theme, comment)
```

So after 5 minutes link to edit must hide from the page (but we need to refresh the page). Here is my code in RSpec for creating comments and testing the link-hide functionality:

```
 def create_comment(options={})
   options[:content] ||= 'I am a comment'

   visit category_theme_path(category, theme)
   within '.comment-form' do
     fill_in 'Content', with: options[:content]
     click_button 'Submit'
   end
 end

 context 'Comment has content' do
   before(:each) { create_comment }

   it 'hides the edit symbol due 5 minutes after comment was created' do
     using_wait_time 400 do
       visit category_theme_path(category, theme)
       save_and_open_page
       expect(page).to have_no_css('.comment-edit')
     end
   end

 end
```

But I got: `Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_no_css('.comment-edit')expected #has_no_css?(".comment-edit") to return true, got false`

I also try to use `page.reload!`, `expect(page).to have_no_css('.comment-edit', wait: 400)` and other related staff, but capybara don't want to wait. Maybe I use `using_wait_time` for a wrong place, if that - how I can test this?

[image]

Comment: Having your test wait for 5 minutes sounds unacceptable to me. Any other ways you can test this behavior?

Comment: Can you  show your `create_comment` method?

Comment: Is your test actually waiting, or running immediately?

Comment: The last way. I add action create above in original post.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't test this little js code but instead write a test to make sure the edit functionality is indeed forbidden on the controller. People leave a page open for 5 minutes? Really?

Comment: No, edit functionality is in it's place I just not published it here, comment can be edited in 5 minutes after creation, then link must disappear.

Comment: @k1r8r0wn have you enable `js` for testing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean under js enabling? There is no ajax here, maybe I use  'using_wait_time' for a wrong place?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your approach to testing this.  The reason your attempt is failing is because using_wait_time just sets the amount of time Capybaras matchers will wait for their expectations to become true, it doesn't actually make the program wait. Therefore `expect(page).to have_no_css('.comment-edit')`  will wait up to the time your `using_wait_time` specifies, rechecking the page every 50 milliseconds or so for the content, but it never reloads the page and doesn't wait before the loading the page.  For your approach to work you would need to sleep before visiting the page

```
it 'hides the edit symbol due 5 minutes after comment was created' do
  sleep 5.minutes      
  visit category_theme_path(category, theme)
  save_and_open_page
  expect(page).to have_no_css('.comment-edit')
end
```

however this is a terrible idea since your tests will become ridiculously slow.

Rather than that approach you could be generating your test comment already "old" (as pascal betz suggests), using something like FactoryGirl and specifying a created_at that is more than 5 minutes ago.

```
FactoryGirl.create(:comment, created_at: 5.minutes.ago)
```

or if you want to continue creating your comment through the interface then include something like the [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem and you can do

```
 Timecop.travel(5.minutes.from_now) do
   visit category_theme_path(category, theme)
   save_and_open_page
   expect(page).to have_no_css('.comment-edit')
 end
```

which will move the clock 5 minutes forward before visiting the page, and then reset it back to normal once the block if finished.

Additionally, your `editable?` method is comparing in the wrong direction and should be

```
def editable?
  self.created_at > (Time.now - 5.minute)
end
```

Then the view should be

```
- if comment.editable?
  = link_to 'Edit', edit_category_theme_comment_path(@category, @theme, comment)
```

Comment: Much appreciated for your time providing great explanation! I deal with it by adding `Comment.last.update(created_at: 5.minutes.ago)` and after that see your answer.  Also will try to use `Timecop` gem just for test it.

Answer (score 1):

Work with seed data that is 5 minutes old and visit that page. Like this you do not need to wait five minutes.

Also your code

```
- unless comment.editable?
  = link_to 'Edit', edit_category_theme_comment_path(@category, @theme, comment)
```

should probably read

```
- if comment.editable?
  = link_to 'Edit', edit_category_theme_comment_path(@category, @theme, comment)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, also it's a good remark about using `if`.